# Validation Laravel required_if?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have the following validation rule:

```
 "email_work" => "unique:users,email,".$user_id."|email|required_if:is_seller,1",
```

It requests field `email_work` despite there is not `is_seller = 1` in request.
What I doing wrong?

Comment: Why is the **`".$user_id."`** concatenated to the validation rules?

Comment: Sorry it shuld be removed, but issue is leave

Comment: Change the sequence of the validation rules! **`"email_work" => "required_if:is_seller,1|unique:users,email|email|",`**

Comment: It work still the same

Comment: So, I need to make others fiels required only when I have `is_set` value went from form

Comment: **`is_seller`** is that field there in form?

Comment: Yes, it is in first